# F# R Type Provider - Anova: Formula with Factor and Error

Tags: r, f#, data-analysis, type-providers

How do I write a formula with more level factors and errors (i've managend to do an anova without more level factor)?

In R I'd write something like this

```
factor=as.factor(table$luck)
anova=aov(MeanRT ~ factor + Error(Person) , data=table)
```

In F# I have this so far:

```
let factor = R.as_factor(table.["Luck"]).AsFactor()

let df=
    (namedParams [
            "Luck", box (luck|> List.map (fun (a,b,c) -> a));
            "Person", box (luck |> List.map (fun (a,b,c) -> b));
            "MeanRT", box (luck |> List.map (fun (a,b,c) -> c));
            "glFactor", box glFactor;
            ]
        |> R.data_frame).AsDataFrame()

let anovaLuck = R.lm(formula = "MeanRT~factor + Error(Person)", data= df, paramArray = [|glFactor|] )
```

Even without the part in front of 'Error' i dont get the same Anova-Table as I would in R.

With the 'Error(Person') i get following Exception

```
RDotNet.EvaluationException: Error in Error(Person) : could not find function "Error"

   at RDotNet.REngine.Parse(String statement, StringBuilder incompleteStatement)
   at RDotNet.REngine.<Defer>d__46.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.LastOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at RDotNet.REngine.Evaluate(String statement)
   at RProvider.Internal.Logging.logWithOutput[a](CharacterDeviceInterceptor characterDevice, FSharpFunc`2 f) in C:\FSharp\RProvider\src\RProvider\Logging.fs:line 65
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0069>.$FSI_0069.main@() in C:\...\Program.fsx:line 614
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `R.lm`? Does it work if you change it to `R.aov`?

Comment: With the 'normal' anova i went with  R.lm and R.anova. With R.aov i get  ```  Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors ```